# How can I fix error longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, adehabitathr

I am using the `kerneloverlaphr` function to estimate the overlap of 10 Home range, however I get

> error longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

How can I fix it?
However, I get the matrix that compares the pairs, but I get this error. Does it have any effect on the result, or does it not matter?

```
kernel.lscv <- kernelUD(turtles.sp, grid = 300, h = "LSCV",
                        extent = 0.1, same4all = FALSE, kern = "bivnorm", boundary = NULL)

#to determine kernelUD 95%
turtlesHR95<-getverticeshr(kernel.lscv,percent=95, unin = c ("m"), unout = c("km2"))

#to determine Overlap's home ranges
kerneloverlaphr(kernel.lscv, method = "UDOI", percent = 95, conditional = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include relevant packages (ie, do all of these functions come from the `adehabitatHR` package?)?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.